# Deriving binding from existing SwiftUI @States

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I've been playing around with SwiftUI and Combine and feel like there is probably a way to get a hold of the existing @State properties in a view and create a new one.

For example, I have a password creation View which holds a password and a passwordConfirm field for the user. I want to take those two @State properties and derive a new @State that I can use in my view that asserts if the input is valid. So for simplicity: not empty and equal.

The Apple docs say [there is a publisher](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding/3264174-publisher) on a binding, though I can't appear to get ahold of it.

This is some non-functioning pseudo code:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct CreatePasswordView : View {
    @State var password = ""
    @State var confirmation = ""
    lazy var valid = {
        return self.$password.publisher()
            .combineLatest(self.$confirmation)
            .map { $0 != "" && $0 == $1 }
    }

    var body: some View {
        SecureField($password, placeholder: Text("password"))

        SecureField($confirmation, placeholder: Text("confirm password"))

        NavigationButton(destination: NextView()) { Text("Done") }
            .disabled(!valid)
    }
}
```

Anyone found. the appropriate way of going about this / if it's possible?

UPDATE Beta 2:

As of beta 2 publisher is available so the first half of this code now works. The second half of using the resulting publisher within the View I've still not figured out (`disabled(!valid)`).

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct CreatePasswordView : View {
    @State var password = ""
    @State var confirmation = ""

    lazy var valid = {
        Publishers.CombineLatest(
            password.publisher(),
            confirmation.publisher(),
            transform: { String($0) != "" && $0 == $1 }
        )
    }()

    var body: some View {
        SecureField($password, placeholder: Text("password"))

        SecureField($confirmation, placeholder: Text("confirm password"))

        NavigationButton(destination: NextView()) { Text("Done") }
            .disabled(!valid)
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried just `var valid: Bool { password != "" && password == confirmation }`? Since both `password` and `confirmation` are `@State`, `body` would be always recomputed when they change and `valid` will reflect the new states

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio I think that's the right idea

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't be playing with `@State/@Published` as `Combine` is in beta at the moment, but here's a simple workaround for what you're trying to achieve.

I'd implement a view model to hold password, password confirmation, and whether it's valid or not

```swift
class ViewModel: NSObject, BindableObject {

    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    var password: String = "" {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(())
        }
    }

    var passwordConfirmation: String = "" {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(())
        }
    }

    var isPasswordValid: Bool {
        return password == passwordConfirmation && password != ""
    }

}
```

In this way, the view is recomputed anytime the password or the confirmation changes.

Then I would make a `@ObjectBinding` to the view model.

```swift
struct CreatePasswordView : View {

    @ObjectBinding var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                SecureField($viewModel.password,
                            placeholder: Text("password"))
                SecureField($viewModel.passwordConfirmation,
                            placeholder: Text("confirm password"))
                NavigationButton(destination: EmptyView()) { Text("Done") }
                    .disabled(!viewModel.isPasswordValid)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I had to put the views in a `NavigationView`, because `NavigationButton` doesn't seem to enable itself if it isn't in one of them.

Comment: Why do you say Combine is bugged? Any major issue that you have come across with Combine?

Comment: @SMP I meant `beta` - also the Swift compiler isn't fully ready for `@propertyWrapper/@propertyDelegate attributes` like `@State/@Published`. Last, the Foundation integration is not working as per [Xcode 11 beta release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_beta_release_notes) - search for 51241500.

Comment: appreciate this, thanks. I had actually tried this approach, though I'm actually wanting to do more then just that simple validation and want to make a network request with debounce as well (to check https://haveibeenpwned.com API for compromised passwords). Apple have WWDC videos of a similar thing integrating UIKit+Combine - maybe Combine+SwiftUI just isn't there yet or they have something alternative in mind.

Comment: @freebie it was suspicious that it was mostly slides, rather than live coding - they didn't want to risk the red dots!

Answer (score 1):

What you need here is a *computed property*. As the name suggests, its value is re-computed every time the property is accessed. If you use `@State` variables to calculate the property, SwiftUI will automatically re-compute the body of the View whenever `valid` is changed:

```
struct CreatePasswordView: View {
    @State var password = ""
    @State var confirmation = ""

    private var valid: Bool {
        password != "" && password == confirmation
    }

    var body: some View {
        SecureField($password, placeholder: Text("password"))

        SecureField($confirmation, placeholder: Text("confirm password"))

        NavigationLink(destination: NextView()) { Text("Done") }
            .disabled(!valid)
    }
}
```